# Prevent Proguard from removing unused Properties

Tags: android, proguard, greendao, android-proguard

I have a class:

```
public static class Properties {
    public final static Property Id = new Property(0, String.class, "id", true, "ID");
    public final static Property Name = new Property(1, String.class, "name", false, "NAME");
    public final static Property Email = new Property(2, String.class, "email", false, "EMAIL");
    public final static Property ValidatedAt = new Property(3, long.class, "validatedAt", false, "VALIDATED_AT");
};
```

And the following proguard rule:

```
-keep class **$Properties
```

However when I assemble a release build here is the output:

```
public class UserDao$Properties
{
  public static final f a;
  static
  {
    a = new f(0, String.class, "id", true, "ID");
    new f(1, String.class, "name", false, "NAME");
    new f(2, String.class, "email", false, "EMAIL");
    new f(3, Long.TYPE, "validatedAt", false, "VALIDATED_AT");
  }
}
```

(from the decompiled APK)

Notice only the Id field has been set, the other three have not (even though their constructors are present).

The other three fields are not used in code but are used by GreenDAO using reflection.

How do I prevent the other three fields from being removed?

I have tried

```
-keepclassmembers class **$Properties {
    public final static Property *;
}
```

along with the rule above but it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly keep the contents of your `Properties` class: `-keep class **$Properties { *; }`? Alternatively, you could try keeping inner classes around too: `-keepattributes InnerClasses`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
-keepclassmembers class **$Properties {
    public static <fields>;
}
```